# How can i add multiple views to one view without conflict on scripts?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to add multiple views to one view, but it conflicts with scripts and repeating IDs. These previsualization views before converting to PDF files are generating charts. What I do to add the multiple views is the following.

```
 $view .= view('system.administrator.history.pdf.layout-multiple', 
     compact('sample', 'samples', 'tests'))->render(); // These are in a foreach loop

return $view; // This is what I received at the AJAX function and is sent to a form element hidden to send data to a new view
```

The function to add multiple views at one is working. My problem is with scripts and IDs. Any solutions?

Comment: you can create a script.blade.php file and add all the scripts there.

Comment: and you should also check for variables if some variable is present then load the script

Comment: like you have a view for your `$sample` variable
then you should do like 
`@if($sample)
 <script src="scriptForSampleView.js"></script>
@endif`